# Steel hamstrings

Tags: muscle, stretching, hamstring

My hamstrings have always been incredibly tight. 
Since I have memories, never been able to raise a straight leg at more than 30-45° from the ground. 
Can't do any L-sit,leg raises, romenian deadlift etcetera.
My deadlift looks more like a squat off the floor. 
Been doing daily stretches for almost a year now and haven't noticed any progress.
Feels like my hams are made of immobile steel, they just won't get more flexible.

Is my problem structural  or is it supposed to take some more years before I see some progress?

Comment: What are you doing for stretches, and when do you do them? Before/after working out? How many times a week? For how long?

Comment: You may want to get checked for anterior pelvic tilt. If your hip flexors get too short they can pull the front of your pelvis down. In return, this will pull your hamstrings tight. Generally, hamstring strengthening exercises are one of the best things for this, while stretching the hamstrings is the opposite of what you’d want. https://youtu.be/K-CrEi0ymMg

Answer (score 1):

Hamstrings are only part of long structure. Issue can be higher, or lower, or all together. Look for "superficial back line, Myers". As a prove - roll your feet - like [here](https://redefiningstrength.com/4-exercises-to-prevent-foot-and-ankle-pain/). Lacrosse ball is perfect for that. Then try if it help in your motion range. Most of us can do dead lift, squat easier.

Had same problem, and decide to stretch / mobilize - for two reasons - injury prevention, and moving exercise from edge of my motion range.

There is group of exercises that worked for me. They are done with door-frame. So you lie down with one leg rised on door-frame. That is the leg you are working on. Other one is slowly moving up, and down, or slides on the ground. All moves slow, with small tension. At start do that for an hour every day - note that you can do what ever you want with hands. Books, podcasts, what not. 
The exercises are shown at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJFLr2Vz9WY) video, yes he is talking in Polish... Sorry for that. If you have questions, I can do some translations. He is naming exercises in English, but can't find them - by that names. Once again - sorry for non-English content, but that is something worked perfectly well in my case. Simple easy exercises, done with no pain.